# How to solve Window leaked Exception in Android while changing the from landscape to portrait or vice versa?

Tags: android

I am getting the exception of window leaked changing the from landscape to portrait or vice versa ?

Comment: you should add more about your question. eg. logcat output, source code where you are getting error, what you are trying to do,...

Answer (score 2):

It usually happens when Something like A `progressDialog or Dialog` is open and Its `Parent Activity` gets `Finished`...  SO make sure to `dismiss` it before Activity gets finished